# std::tuple of const references?

Tags: c++, c++11, tuples, pass-by-reference

I had a function which used to be called as

```
void func(const A& v0, const A& v1, const A& v2);
```

For clarity, I would like to pass the arguments as a 3-tuple. What is the right way if any additional overhead is to be avoided? Is the following going to be the most efficient?:

```
void func(std::tuple<const A&> v);
```

Comment: I'd also pass the tuple as const reference for efficency

Comment: Are A's polymorphic? Are three of them often used together?

Comment: @BartoszMilewski: not polymorphic; often used together.

Comment: What data does `A` actually contain?

Answer (score 0):

If they are not polymorphic and often used (and, I assume, created) together then why don't you just pack them into a value tuple, `std::tuple<A, A, A>`, or a named struct. You would pass it around by const reference. This solution has no performance overhead and, in fact, may be faster.

Actually, since all three elements are of the same type, why don't you use an array of three elements, `A[3]`? Tuples are best for heterogenous types.

Comment: `std::array<A,3>`… but in any case the type should be typedef'd to a friendly, refactorable name.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: You can typedef the array to a friendly name. I'm not sure what you mean by refactorable. Could you provide code examples with tuple and array?